# Issue with reading multiple text box entries in VBA at once

Tags: vba, ms-access, quickbooks

Simple question, how can I take something entered in a textbox and enter it into QuickBooks from Access. I have no problems with connecting Access to QuickBooks but am receiving a syntax error.

**This hard coded input works:**

```
sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"
sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name) values ('Testing VB')"
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Record Added!!!"
MsgBox sMsg


Set oRecordset = Nothing
Set oConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

**This is what I am trying to get  to work (input from text box):**

```
cust = Forms.form1.customerName

sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"


sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name) values" & cust & ")"

Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Record Added!"
MsgBox sMsg


Set oRecordset = Nothing
Set oConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Update (what about multiple entries at once?**

```
cust = Forms.form1.customerName
company = Forms.form1.companyName

sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"


sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name), (CompanyName) values ('" & cust & "'), ('" & companyName & "') "
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not forming the dynamic SQL correctly. You need to adjust your code as follows  `sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name) values ('" & cust & "')"` making note of the extra bracket to surround the values, and also the text qualifier quotes.

Comment: What if I have say multiple fields?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Then you'd include them in the field list and the value list as normal. `Insert into customer (field1, field2, field3) values ('" & field1value & "','" & field2value & "','" & field3value & "')` assuming they're all string fields.

Comment: Please do not advise how to fix string concatenation used for parameters in an SQL query. [It is wrong anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).